# Why netbeans not formatting the code properly?

Tags: php, netbeans, formatting, text-editor

Why netbeans is not formatting the code properly?

The html code is not aligned/formatted properly between div's. See code below, try and paste this in to netbeans and press **Alt + Shift + F**

```
<div id="header">
    <strong class="logo"></strong>
    <?php if ($showHeaderLogout): ?>
        <div style="float:right; margin-right: 20px">                        
            <div> Logged in as <span style="font-weight:bold"> ?????? </span> </div>                           
        </div>                
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>                        

    <div class="nav-block">                        
    <?php if ($showNav): ?>
            <ul id="nav">                                                
                <li><a <?php echo ($headerActive == "home") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="/home">Home</a></li>
            </ul>                                                
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of NetBeans do you use? I use 7.0 and it auto formats the snippet pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a "bug" of netbeans formatter that get lost mixing php environment for indentation using constructions like if: and endif; and html.

For those cases I indent the code myself.